# How to sort multindex columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, multi-index

I am trying to manipulate a bunch of multiindex Pandas array. Each column is a time series with different categorical groupings.  I would like to sort through the data and then parse through all the categories and then do some additional data manipulation.  Here is a sample code of what I was attempting but didn't work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'t': range(1,11)})
df.set_index(['t'],inplace=True)

for num in range(2):
    labely = (str(num),'A','y')
    labelx = (str(num),'A','x')
    labelbx = (str(num),'B','x')
    df[labelx]= np.random.randn(10)
    df[labelbx]= np.random.randn(10)
    df[labely]= np.random.randn(10)+range(1,11)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns, names=['ID','Location','Direction']) 

df[('0','A','tot')]=df[('0','A','y')]+df[('0','A','x')]
df.sort_index(level='ID',inplace=True)
df.head()
```

This doesn't sort. This is the result with the total not being grouped with the other 0 ID and the Locations not being grouped together:

```
ID                0                        ...            1                   0
Location          A         B         A    ...            B         A         A
Direction         x         x         y    ...            x         y       tot
t                                          ...                                 
1          0.430386 -0.121109  0.263314    ...     0.243839  0.313505  0.693700
2         -1.262746 -0.678889  1.289814    ...    -0.893230  0.373103  0.027068
3          0.245483 -0.565859  3.766628    ...     0.012933  1.652484  4.012111
4          1.518357  0.447032  5.649877    ...    -1.205161  5.513507  7.168233
5         -0.095216 -0.571333  6.794958    ...    -0.777933  4.073334  6.699741
```

I have 2 questions associated with this.

1. How to I sort the columns so that the organized by each of the
   levels
2. How do I efficiently parse through the dataframe to do
   additional data manipulation .

This is some sudo code for the second questions

```
for id in ID: 
     for loc in Location:
               df[(id,loc,'tot')=df[(id,loc,'x')]+df[(id,loc,'y')]
```

Comment: The `sort_index` has a parameter `axis` default to 0, which means sort on index. You need `axis=1` to sort on columns.

Comment: Thank you.  That works perfectly.   That solves question #1.  Still not sure how to parse through the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by columns, as Ian answered axis=1:

```
df.sort_index(level='ID',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

To get a list of the tuples of the unique column names to parse, I needed columns.values and then I resorted after calculations.

```
for id,loc,dir in df.columns.values:
    df[(id,loc,'tot')]=(df[(id,loc,'x')]**2+df[(id,loc,'y')]**2)**.5
df.sort_index(level='ID',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Since this is basic column calculations I think this method would be efficient.